# Installing Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.ps1 - PnP-Powershell responsive package

Tags: powershell, pnp, responsive-template

I'm trying to install the Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.ps1 but i'm stuck with the options listed.
I want to use the PNP-Poweshell responsive package.
I typed in " **SharePoint Online**" and enter but it doesn't accept it 
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Please check the commands here...https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: Error The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Is a problem with Windows 8?